# API Requests that need Authorization return CORS error

Tags: api, nginx, axios, jwt, cors

## Initial Problem

I work on a web application (react) that accesses data via an API. The API runs for development reasons on a docker container on my local machine. Simple GET requests (via axios) got me CORS complications (`...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`).

A bit of researching solved my problem by running a nginx reverse proxy in another container. I basically used [this configuration](https://github.com/maximillianfx/docker-nginx-cors) for the nginx server.

## New Problem

As I progress in building my application, I come to a point where I need to send the JWT to the API to access and alter some entries. Requests that need sending a JWT again get me CORS error messages.

The API checks the JWT signature (RS256 generated). I just have to forward it to the API server.

**ALSO**: simple curl requests with the JWT from the console are working.

## Configuration

- axios

```
const axiosConfig = {
    responseType: "json",
    withCredentials: false,
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer <JWT as string>',
    },
};

const apiGetRequest = async (route, callback) => {
    try {
        const apiUrl = URL + route;
        axios.get(apiUrl, {
            axiosConfig
        })
            .then(res => {
                callback(res);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

- [nginx configuration](https://github.com/maximillianfx/docker-nginx-cors)
- Docker Image for api

```
version: "3.9"

services:

    db:
        image: mariadb:latest
        container_name: db
        env_file:
            - ./mariadb/.env
        volumes:
            - ./mariadb/create-schema-docker.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306

    rest:
        image: mds4ul/station-registry:latest
        container_name: api
        environment:
            - DB_HOST=db
            - CONTEXT_PATH=api
        env_file:
            - ./rest/.env
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - 80:8080

volumes:
    db-data:
```

## Questions

1. Why do I get CORS errors for requests where a jwt is needed and not for requests that do not require one?
2. Which part do I have to change to make this work?

Comment: Hi, where is your Axios config ? inside your React app ? And what is your Nginx conf ? Is it the standard one provides in your link ?

Comment: Hi @JoffreyK, does axios has a seperate config file? The axios code I posted is inside the react app. The nginx conf is the standard one in the link. I just changed some ports.

Comment: No Axios conf is in the right place but `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` config should be in the server side (your API). You can manage CORS with a proxy like you attempt to but you need to "proxify" your API requests.

Comment: okay, unfortunately I cannot access the server side. So I am wondering why some requests work with the reverse proxy and for others I get a CORS error and not other error messages

Comment: Could you be more specific ? Can you share both requests (with url) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So answer another question to an embarrassing easy problem of mine.

I switched to an express.js proxy server with the following configuration:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const axios = require('axios')
const cors = require('cors')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

require('dotenv').config()

const headers = {
    "X-Authorization": <token>,
}

app.get(':endpoint([\\/\\w\\.-]*)', function (req, res) {
    const endpoint = (process.env.API_BASE_URL).replace(/\/$/, "") + req.params.endpoint;
    axios.get(endpoint, { headers }).then(response => {
        res.json(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
        res.json(error)
    })
})
app.listen(3001)
```

I assume I just could not figure out my nginx configuration for this use case. So with express.js I can access now resources which need authorization.

Comment: So you hardcode your token, What if it expire ?

Comment: Why putting a url matching a regex in a request params ? It looks like a very weird solution. Use `*` instead and req object already contains all what you want.
`app.get('*', (req, res) => {`
`const endpoint =` `\`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}${req.origineUrl}\`;`
`...`
`}`

Comment: This is not a solution for a productive environment. We have to eventually change the live api to accept RS256 signed tokens. Right now the api only accepts SH256 signed ones. So on my local machine I generated and hardcoded a token that is accepted for a longer time just for testing purposes of the UI.

In our live environment we have a working proxy. If this will go live we probably won't use the one I created with express.js locally. But I appreciate the tip with the url solution and will change it according to your suggestion.